# Syntax error (-201) why?

Tags: sql, informix

Why am I getting syntax error in this SPL procedure? Only message I got is that exists some error while using syntax check in server studio.

```
create function najboljihN(n smallint)
returning char(10) as jmbag, char(50) as prezime, char(50) as ime, decimal(3,2) as prosjek;

   define jmbag like student.jmbag;
   define prezime like student.prezime;
   define ime like student.ime;
   define prosjek decimal(3,2);
   define i integer;

  for i=1 to n step 1
 SELECT student.jmbag, 
   student.prezimestudent, 
   student.imestudent, 
   Avg(ocjena) 
 INTO   jmbag, prezime, ime, prosjek 
FROM   student 
   JOIN upisanpredmet 
     ON student.jmbag = upisanpredmet.jmbag 
GROUP  BY student.jmbag, 
      student.prezimestudent, 
      student.imestudent 
 ORDER  BY ocjena, 
      student.prezimestudent asc, 
      student.imestudent asc; 

 RETURN jmbag, prezime, ime, ocjena WITH RESUME;
 end for;

end function;
```

Comment: I can't find any mention of a `-201` error on the Information Center pages for any DB2 platform I'm familiar with (z/OS, LUW, iSeries)... are you sure that's the message you're getting? Could you paste the full text of the error you get?

Comment: @bhamby SPL is the Informix programming language; the DB2 tag does not belong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the order by clause in this case. Without the order by clause you can compile your function.

```
create function najboljihN(n smallint)
     returning char(10) as jmbag, char(50) as prezime, char(50) as ime, decimal(3,2) as prosjek;

        define jmbag like student.jmbag;
        define prezime like student.prezime;
        define ime like student.ime;
        define prosjek decimal(3,2);
        define i integer;

        for i = 1 to n step 1
      SELECT jmbag, 
        prezimestudent, 
         imestudent, 
        Avg(ocjena) 
      INTO   jmbag, prezime, ime, prosjek 
     FROM   student 
        JOIN upisanpredmet 
          ON student.jmbag = upisanpredmet.jmbag 
     GROUP  BY student.jmbag, 
           student.prezimestudent, 
           student.imestudent; 
     -- ORDER  BY ocjena, 
     --      student.prezimestudent asc, 
     --      student.imestudent asc; 

      RETURN jmbag, prezime, ime, prosjek WITH RESUME;
      end for;

     end function;
```

I do not exactly understand what you intend with your loop, because you do n times the same sql. But if this is realy your intention you can write the results into a temp table and then return your values from the temp table.

```
CREATE FUNCTION najboljihN(n SMALLINT)
   RETURNING CHAR(10) AS jmbag, CHAR(50) AS prezime, CHAR(50) AS ime, DECIMAL(3, 2) AS prosjek;

   DEFINE jmbag LIKE student.jmbag;
   DEFINE prezime LIKE student.prezime;
   DEFINE ime LIKE student.ime;
   DEFINE prosjek DECIMAL(3, 2);
   DEFINE i INTEGER;

 -- CREATE Temp Table    
   CREATE TEMP TABLE t1(
            jmbag     CHAR(10),
            prezime   CHAR(50),
            ime       CHAR(50),
            prosjek   DECIMAL(3, 2))

 -- Fill Temp Table
   FOR i = 1 TO n step 1 

INSERT INT t1
       SELECT jmbag, prezimestudent, imestudent, Avg(ocjena) as prosjek
       FROM student JOIN upisanpredmet ON student.jmbag = upisanpredmet.jmbag
       GROUP BY student.jmbag, student.prezimestudent, student.imestudent;

   END FOR;

 -- Return from temp table
   FOREACH
       SELECT jmbag, prezimestudent, imestudent, prosjek 
    INTO jmbag, prezime, ime, prosjek
       FROM t1 ORDER BY prosjek

       RETURN jmbag, prezime, ime, prosjek WITH RESUME;

   END FOREACH;

END FUNCTION;
```

Comment: tnx :) 
But can you give me link to literatore or explain yourself why order by cause syntax error? And how can I sort, in this case above so it doesn't give error?

Comment: @Error, i added a solution for your sorting problem.

Answer (score 2):

The [Informix manuals says](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0157.htm#ids_sqs_0157?lang=en) :

> The ORDER BY clause implies that the query returns more than one row.
>   In SPL, the database server issues an error if you specify the ORDER
>   BY clause without a FOREACH loop to process the returned rows
>   individually within the SPL routine.